# How to improve the performance of neo4j-jdbc-driver?

Tags: java, performance, neo4j

How could I improve the performance of neo4j-jdbc-driver? I use MVC structure to implement my code. It seems cost about 3~5 second to build an Apache HTTP client, so I think to best way is to reduce the http connection. But why below code will three times "Starting the Apache HTTP client"?, I think I only build http connection once.

***Console Log***

```
Starting the Apache HTTP client
Starting the Apache HTTP client
->Columns: [node] current row -1: null
Starting the Apache HTTP client
Stopping the HTTP client
```

***Neo4jServiceTester.java***

```
@Test
public void findNodeTester() {
    try {
        String UUID = "306C0F88-0A26-41EA-A954-DFC7025402DC";
        neo4jService.findNode(UUID);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

***Neo4jService.java***

```
public void findNode(String UUID) throws Exception {
    Neo4jConnection connection = new Driver().connect("jdbc:neo4j://172.11.13.23:7474?debug=true", new Properties());
    connection.setAutoCommit(false);
    NodeBean node;
    try {
        node = neo4jDAO.findNode(connection, UUID);
        System.out.println("node=" + node.toString());
        connection.commit();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        connection.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    connection.close(); 
}
```

***BaseNeo4jDAO.java***

```
public NodeBean findNode(Neo4jConnection connection, String UUID) throws Exception {
    String queryStr = "MATCH (n) WHERE n.UUID = \"" + UUID + "\" RETURN { id : ID(n), labels : labels(n), properties: n } as node";
    Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(queryStr); 
    rs.next();
    NodeBean node = new NodeBean();
    BeanUtils.populate(node, (Map<String, Object>) rs.getObject("node"));
    return node;
}
```

**Updated:**

It seems to print "Starting the Apache HTTP client" in below situations:

```
1. Neo4jConnection connection = neo4jDB.getConnection();
2. ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(queryStr);
3. connection.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this just once in your program, and pass the connection in.

```
Neo4jConnection connection = new Driver().connect("jdbc:neo4j://172.11.13.23:7474?debug=true", new Properties());
connection.setAutoCommit(false);
```

Comment: Are there any way to implement connection pool? Since there will be many users, it is impossible to build only one connection.

Comment: I found an interesting thing, when I use the eclipse in osx to connect to the neo4j server in redhat, it cost only one second to get the result. But when I use the eclipse in windows, it cost more than six seconds to get the result. The codes are the same...